# Java Conversion from ASCII Integer to Character yields unknown values

Tags: java, char, type-conversion, ascii

I have some Java code that should be very simple and straightforward, and unfortunately, I'm getting very odd results.

Put simply, I'm doing a basic conversion from ASCII integers back into their string values.

For instance, if I do:

```
char n = (char) 152;

System.out.print(n); // should yield: ÿ.
```

Unfortunately, this is simply yielding: `?`

Anybody have any familiarity with this type of problem?

Comment: There should be a semi-colon after print statement.

Comment: Yes thank you, this is my first question that I've actually posted since I've been able to find pretty much every problem I've had on here, so I guess I'm a little sloppy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UTF16, the character ÿ is decimal code 255. Decimal code 152 is a control character called "start of string". http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0098/index.htm

You may be looking at, for example, [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/) extended codes, but these codes do not apply to Java which is UTF16.

Comment: Ok.  I will need to get java to use a different encoding type?  I assume I need UTF-8?

Comment: In UTF-8 the code point would still be 255. Good catch by Radiodef! If you look at the code chart for the [Latin-1 Supplement (PDF)](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) you will see the codes for all these characters. `'ÿ'` is the last one in that block.

Comment: Java `char` is always considered a UTF16 code. The library provides means to *convert from byte arrays in other encodings* but I can't say for sure if that's what you need to do. Perhaps the thing to do is to ask a new question pertaining to the program you are writing.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the comment Radiodef and David Conrad.  I will mark the answer complete iff I can figure out a solution to my problem, and will link it to any new question that I make.

Answer (score 1):

The console you are printing out to may not support displaying that character.

Have you tried

`System.out.println("ÿ");`

To see if your console can display this character?

Comment: It's also possible the console *does* support it, but there's a mismatch between the encoding Java is emitting and what the console is expecting.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft command prompt.  Interestingly enough, it's not that it's simply unable to print the string.  I'm doing a comparison between an original string with ascii values and converting numbers from their integer ascii values to then see if the two strings are equal.  In any case, the ÿ is yielded as part of the original string and when i try to explictly print it i get some weird upside down 4, but when i print the cast i get a ?.  Thanks for the response tho

Comment: @DavidConrad, This is part of a larger problem i was having but in an effort to figure out what was going on I noticed that if i explicitly try and cast "(char) 152" it yields me with a ?, so I'm not sure how encoding would have anything to do with it as I'm hardcoding 152.

Answer (score 1):

When you print the `char` it is converted to your default platform encoding, which might be Windows-1252 or who-knows-what. You probably need to tell Java what encoding your terminal is using, but you need to know what that is.

For instance, on my system, I would need to run your class with a `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` switch, since my terminal (mintty under cygwin) is expecting UTF-8, but Java is defaulting to Windows-1252 (or, Cp1252) on Windows 7.

Additionally, as Radiodef pointed out, 152 is a Unicode control character; the correct code point for `ÿ` is 255.